# R Loop Index skipping values

Tags: r

```
SEQ = seq(1,2,.1)
FORMULA = numeric(length(SEQ))

for (i in SEQ) {
FORMULA1 = i^2
  # Store the results in the vectors
  FORMULA[i] <- FORMULA1
}
```

I know that the issue is in the index FORMULA[i] but I do not know how to fix this and I wish to do so

Comment: You need to index on integers. Your index `i` is currently `1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ... 2.0`, which doesnt make sense as an index (try running `SEQ[1.1]` or `SEQ[1.4]` etc, and see what you get)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do it directly?

```
SEQ = seq(1,2,.1)
FORMULA <- SEQ^2

> FORMULA
 [1] 1.00 1.21 1.44 1.69 1.96 2.25 2.56 2.89 3.24 3.61 4.00
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
Here is an update with the input of @zx8754 (many thanks):

```
SEQ = seq(1, 2, .1)
FORMULA = numeric(length(SEQ))

for (i in seq_along(SEQ)) {
  FORMULA[i] <- SEQ[i]^2
}
FORMULA
```

**First answer:**
Instead of `FORMULA1 = i^2` do `FORMULA1 = SEQ[i]^2`:

```
SEQ = seq(1, 2, .1)
FORMULA = numeric(length(SEQ))

for (i in 1:length(SEQ)) {
  FORMULA1 = SEQ[i]^2
  # Store the results in the vectors
  FORMULA[i] <- FORMULA1
}
FORMULA
```

```
 [1] 1.00 1.21 1.44 1.69 1.96 2.25 2.56 2.89 3.24 3.61 4.00
```

Comment: seq_along would be safer: `seq_along(vector(length = 0))` vs `1:length(vector(length = 0))`